# get_template_directory_uri() gives me wrong path when I try to use wp_enqueue_style

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, css

In my functions.php I use wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script as I read this is the correct way to add stylesheets and scripts to pages. But as my host has this sub folder where the install goes into get_template_directory_uri() gives me the wrong path.

It gives me http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/style.css?ver=1.0"

I need it to be http://www.example.com/subfolder/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/style.css?ver=1.0"

I have no clue at the moment.

Comment: Please post your code so that people can see what it is that you're doing. It's hard to say how you might be doing it wrong when you don't show how you're actually doing anything.

Comment: What are the values for your site's urls in WP Dashboard->Settings->General?  There are entries for both Site Address (URL) and WordPress Address (URL).  Your WordPress Address (URL) should be set to http://www.example.com/subfolder/

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem with a proper subdirectory install (I run subdirectory installs all the time on my dev stack), so I am leaning towards thinking that the host have something configured incorrectly. I don't know if it as easy as what @RachelBaker suggests or if there are `.htaccess` or other hard-coded problems.

Comment: What Rachel said should work just fine. If it doesn't check your `.thaccess`